# Laravel error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`.

There is a  field `expired_at`  in  table `articles`：

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data=[
         'expired_at'=>Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->endOfDay()
    ];

    $article=Article::create(array_merge($request->all(),$data));
    
    return redirect('/artilces');
}
```

view:

```
{{ $article->expired_at->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

error:

> Call to a member function format() on string (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-dev\resources\views\artiles\index.blade.php)

Why is it？

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In your `Article` class add following property:

From Laravel 10.x

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */


protected $casts = [
    'expired_at' => 'datetime'
];
```

[Laravel 10 Upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade)

Before Laravel 10.x you could use

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['expired_at'];
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: If you are building the query via `Eloquent`, then `$dates` works. But, if you are using `Query Builder`, then it doesn't work, you'll have to use the solution given by @NazmulHazan. I haven't tried it with `Raw query`, but, I am sure it will not work with that either.

Comment: It doesn't work with me IDK. I'd already add `protected $dates = ['my_column'];` and run `migrate:fresh` but still get same error. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 67):

I think this is the way. It will not throw error

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->expired_at)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Comment: This is the only way work. The accepted answer doesn't work I don't know why

Comment: But when the column is null it return 1 day before today. For example, the column is null and today is 25 july 2020, so it return 24 july 2020

Answer (score 14):

If you use DB:: to retrieve complex data, you can´t use mutators.
In this situation I use this:

```
{{ date('m-Y', strtotime($hora->Fecha)) }}
```

Or

```
{{ date('m-Y', strtotime($hora ?? ''->Fecha)) }}
```

Where "Fecha" is a datetime value.

Comment: cleaner to read than the above answer, though they both work. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What about this in User.php or your model:

```
protected $casts = [
   'last_active_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Comment: This looks like the answer for Laravel 9

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 10 Update**

The `$dates` property has been [deprecated and removed in Laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#model-dates-property). Instead, you should use the `$casts` property. For example:

```
protected $casts = [
  'expired_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

With, the field declared on $dates of your model.

Try this:

```
optional($article->expired_at)->format('Y-m-d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `expired_at` into datetime in your `Eloquent Model`. You get this error because you are calling `format` function on a String, not a DateTime instance.