# Call to a member function format() on string in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, datetime-format, eloquent

I am trying to get total duration of attendance for specific user. In the method, I am getting the total result but, Now problem is for format the duration time. I am trying like this, but getting error like above. Would someone help me please-
Here is method -

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $id = Auth::id();
  $total_duration = DB::table('attendances')
                    ->select('duration')
                    ->where('teacher_id', '=', $id)
                    ->sum('duration');
  return view('teachers.attendance.index', compact('teacher', 'attendances', 'att_id', 'total_duration'));
 }
```

And in my index.blade.php is -

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">Total</td>
  <td>
       {{ $total_duration->format('H:i:s') }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: That's because `total_duration` is a string and not a [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel error：Call to a member function format() on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533377/laravel-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-string)

Comment: you don't you use timestamp? so and the duration filed should be calculated when the use selected

Comment: I followed this but problem not solved @Allloush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $total_duration return a string, so you can't call function on it. If you want to change format of your date string. you can try that.

Update :  the full code is:

```
$total_duration = DB::table('attendances')->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( 
TIME_TO_SEC( `duration` ) ) ) as total')->first();
```

and $total_duraion->total will be the value you need

Comment: Now Getting this error - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (14924) at position 4 (4): Unexpected character

Comment: It's not calculating total duration properly

Comment: Can you tell me more clearly? What is the result now and what is the result you expected

Comment: As per table column 'duration' values I expected to get the total duration - 01:49:24 in the field total(in view total field). But I get the result 00:00:70 as per your task.

Comment: How do you store duration value in your dtb? Can you please show me the structure of your database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162609/discussion-between-md-rashedul-hasan-and-ngo-tuan).