# Laravel error : Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: laravel

i'm using Laravel 5.6 and i want to make an accessor in my Utility model like this

```
public function getRekomtekDateAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

but when i call `{{ $utility->rekomtek_date }}` the error, as in the title, shown

i've added this line in the same model, as in [Laravel error: Call to a member function format() on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533377/laravel-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-string) , but still no luck

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'rekomtek_date'
];
```

i don't know what's wrong. since i was using Laravel 5.3 this always occur -_-'

Comment: is your `rekomtek_date` of DATE type in the DB? 
Try dumping out the `$value` before formatting and make sure that it is a Carbon type.

Comment: yep, i'm using `$table->date('rekomtek_date');` in my migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass a `$value` to the getter function use it like this:

```
public function getRekomtekDateAttribute()
{
    return $this->rekomtek_date->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Comment: but why in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) at the Defining An Accessor part, it says that we define accessor with that $value variable

Comment: @BangFady Yes, it works well on a string type, but for a date, the conversion to Carbon happens when you access the parent of the field. So your error does not says that the `$value` is empty or null, but that actually it is of type String, and string does not have a format method.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are trying to use format() in a string.
You should do:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
public function getRekomtekDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Comment: You can read a bit in the docs first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators adding the field in a $dates array it casts it to a Carbon instance. Something else is wrong, this is not a solution.

Comment: @navok Yep, BUT the conversion to a Carbon instance takes effect when trying to access the object. E.g. $user->my_date will return a Carbon instance. But when retrieved inside the accessor, it's  not a Carbon instance yet.

Comment: His usage is wrong, look at my answer. It works 100%. I've been using it so many times.